# Android-studio stopped working after updates for API-23

Tags: android, android-studio

I am doing android projects in android studio in ubuntu.I have recently upgraded this android-studio for updates for API 23.After that whenever I tried to run any application it just pops as "Unfortunately the app stopped working".
The above problem occurs for even "Hello world" application.
The below logcat details I got for the application which uses ArrayAdapter and ImageView for listing Countries name and flag.

```
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Before upgrading I have launched the same application successfully.But now I am facing problems.Please provide me a solution.I am sure that there are no errors in my code.

Comment: did you tried clean build ? which version of design library you are using ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that also.com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'

Comment: paste your build.gradle file here

Comment: Did you also try Invalidate Caches and Restart option?

Comment: @AmarAgrawal    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: @Dhina.How to do that?

Comment: @SowmyaRavichandran there must be app level buld.gradle show me that file.Also please upgrade your gradle:1.0.0 to gradle:1.5.0

Comment: @AmarAgrawal.I want to say one more thing.After that update my gradle sync failed.To make changes I have changed that again to api 21.And the modified gradle is

Comment: File->Invalidate/Caches and Restart .. invalidate and restart option

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sowmya.myownbutton"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}

Comment: @Dhina I have tried that also but still showing the same.

Comment: What is the version your compiling against ? I mean `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion`

Comment: @Dhina compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion is 21